# Clojure variadic functions, multiple bindings

Tags: clojure, variadic-functions

Given this example:

`(defn foo [a & [b c :as args]](prn args))`

Is there any way I can add a fourth, optional argument after `b` and `c`?

I've tried this and a few other variations with no success (`CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected parameter`):

`(defn foo [a & [b c :as args d]](prn d))`

..another example (`CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: d in this context`)

`(defn foo [a & [b c :as args & d]](prn d))`

Am I hosed after `:as args` if I want to add more arguments?

EDIT: This was suggested in IRC, and it works, I just wonder if there's a syntactically simpler way...

`(defn foo [a & rst] (let [[b c & d] rst args [b c]] {:a a :b b  c :args args :rst rst}))`

Answer (score 2):

If the pair (b, c) has a special relationship, why not put them together in a nested vector `[]`? this will allow to define a specific binding for it (but add a constraint on the input), e.g.

```
(defn bar [a & [[b c :as args] & rest :as all]]
  {:a a :b b :c c :args args :rest rest :all all})
```

Then:

```
> (bar 1)
{:a 1, :b nil, :c nil, :args nil, :rest nil, :all nil}
```

when you enter the vector `[b c]` you get the binding with `args`:

```
> (bar 1 [2 3])
{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :args [2 3], :rest nil, :all ([2 3])}
```

you can have a vector with one element

```
> (bar 1 [2] 4)
{:a 1, :b 2, :c nil, :args [2], :rest (4), :all ([2] 4)}
```

or no element at all

```
> (bar 1 [] 4 5 6)
{:a 1, :b nil, :c nil, :args [], :rest (4 5 6), :all ([] 4 5 6)}
```

and with all parameters set

```
> (bar 1 [2 3] 4 5 6)
{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :args [2 3], :rest (4 5 6), :all ([2 3] 4 5 6)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the amount of elements in a destructored rest sequence by destructoring it further.

E. g.

```
(defn foo [a & [b c :as args]] args)
(foo 1 2 3 4 5)
;; => (2 3 4 5)
```

Binding the first elements makes no difference. It is the same as if your binding vector was `[a & args]`, only that you have additionally bound the first two elements (`b` and `c`) of `args` by destructoring it further. It is not affected by it.

If you need `args` to have only the first two variadic args, `b` and `c`, and wish to bind the third as an optional `d` one approach would be:

```
(defn foo [a & [b c d :as args]]
  (let [args (seq (take 2 args))]
    ;; ...
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(defn foo [a & [b c d :as args]](prn args))`

Comment: But now `d` is part of `args`, that's not what I want. I want to be able to bind `b` and `c` to one thing, and `d` to something else.

Comment: Someone suggested this in IRC: `(defn foo [a & rst] (let [[b c & d] rst args [b c]] {:a a :b b :c c :args args :rst rst}))`, which works, but is quite a bit more complicated = )